# Redirect route with prepend in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am building a Vuejs app and the routes works this way : `user_role/page` (`user_role` changes depending your role after login) and when they click on the Home button I want to redirect them to their root  `/user_role` no matter what the role is.

First attempt was to add a computed function inside `<router-view :to="homeRoute()">` but it doesn't seem to be ideal.

Second attempt was to add a method, this way:

```
 homeRoute() {
                this.$router.push(this.$route.matched[0].path)
            }
```

I get this error :

> "Navigating to current location ("/client/dashboard") is not allowed".

What would be the ideal way to prepend whatever is after `/user_role/` and redirect to that route ?

Comment: Why not just use `homeRoute() { return this.role_name }` and `<router-link :to="homeRoute"></router-link>` ?

Comment: role_name changes depending your role (/client, /manager, etc.) I used role_name but it is not the actual url.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not redirect depending userType ?

```
goHome : function(){
   const redirectTo = user.accountType === "client" ? {name:'client'} : {name:'manager'}}

   // Catch prevent error if push an active route
   router.push(redirectTo).catch(err => {})
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a bit complicated. One of the user is the admin, so he can change portal. When he clicks on the Home button I want him to be redirected to the root of the portal he was in.